# How to add an image file in opengl using Texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut.h>

void display() {


  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


  int initlist=glGenLists(1);
  glNewList(initlist,GL_COMPILE);


  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
  //GLuint texture = loa // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture 


  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture); 
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0,0,0);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);




  glEnd();
  glPopMatrix();

  glEndList();

  glFlush();
}
```

I Don't know how to **generate a code** of an **image location for texture**. I want to use an image of a road and intend to use that image as a High Way.But i can't get the image location. How can i get that location and use it to **glBindTexture() Function**??

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the image raw data using [glTextImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml), you may load the image using an external library. There are a lot of libraries. I personally like [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-sprite.php).

Edit: You must use [glGenTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGenTextures.xhtml) to create a texture and get a "texture location".

Comment: The value generated by `glGenTexture` is called a 'name' by the spec.